# How to turn off beep on suspend in xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, suspend

When I close the lid or type pm-suspend, I get a beep from my Thinkpad X220 running Xubuntu. How do I remove that beep?

It is louder if the volume is louder, so it's from the regular speakers (also, alsamixer has Beep muted and lsmod says I have neither snd_pcsp nor pcspkr loaded).

I think the beep came with an update some months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I was wrong in guessing the beep came with an update (perhaps I muted volume a lot); on Thinkpads there is a BIOS setting for the beep that comes on all "power events" (plugging cord, suspend, etc.) This fixed it :)